# .on event trigger order in a sequential writes use case

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

let's say I have these clients (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6). Now, c1 writes to database ref to which of of the clients listen. 
Let's say c2 listener on this 'write' triggers and immediately writes to some ref (or removes that node) which all the clients listen also. Is there a guarantee that the 'write of c1' will trigger before (or in case of remove, will it trigger at all) the 'write of c2' in all clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All write operations from a single client are guaranteed to be executed in order, and broadcast out to other clients in that order. So if client 1 performs two writes (write 1 and write 2), then no other (subscribed) client will ever see the result of write 2 before write 1 has been committed.

But there is no guarantee that a client will see all changes. In fact, we explicitly don't synchronize state changes, we synchronize the final state. If write 1 and write 2 modify the same location, there is no guarantee that all clients will get write 1. For example: if a client is temporarily disconnected from the network, it may only see the result of write 2.

This can be especially tricky when the writes cancel each other out. Say that you have a boolean that is currently `true`. Write 1 sets it to `false`, while write 2 sets it back to `true`. If a client is continuously connected, most likely it will see the full sequence: `true` -> `false` -> `true`. But if a client is not connected, it may miss the entire state change and simply see `true` all the time.

I think this likely answers your question: you cannot rely on a client receiving every state change, since Firebase doesn't synchronize state changes. If you want to synchronize state changes, you should store those. So you'd then store a push ID with a command "set to false" and then "set to true" and broadcast those out to the clients (or to a Cloud Function).

Comment: First thanks for your fast answer. I still have a few confusions reading your reply.
_then no other (subscribed) client will ever see the result of write 2 before write 1 has been committed._ This implies that the `writes` are executed as well as broadcasted in order. But this does not mean that they arrive on subscribed client (the ones continuously connected) in that same order, right? _If a client is continuously connected, *most likely* it will see the full sequence_

Comment: Writes from the same client will never arrive out of order. But not all writes are guaranteed to be seen. There are a lot of edge cases. If you require that every client see every state change, store the state changes in your database.

Comment: may I ask one more thing, please. If a client 1 is subscribed to an `child_removed`, event and it disconnects, at that moment client 2 removes the child, and then client 1 reconnects, will it be triggered with that event?
Or even the case in which client 1 subscribes to `remove_child` event of some node after that node is removed already removed by another client?

Comment: Once again: it's easiest once you stop thinking of this as an event flow and start thinking of it as state synchronization. The client fires the events necessary to synchronize its local state with the server state. If the client doesn't have a disk cache, it is easy: when the client starts, it builds a new model of the data for the listener. There is no `child_removed` needed there. If there is a disk cache, it may need a `child_removed` event to remove a child from that cache.

Answer (score 0):

Ordering is not guaranteed. It is possible that rapid changes could trigger function invocations in an unexpected order.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#limitations_and_guarantees